# Linux job scheduler launching a script 2 hours after it terminates

Tags: linux, events, scheduler, jobs

I have a script that runs unknown period of time that depends on its input. It can run one hour when little data available, or it can run for 8 hours if much data is to be processed.
I need to run it periodically, particularly 2 hours after previous run was completed.

Is there an utility to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use 'at' instead of 'cron' and at the end of your script add:

```
at now +2 hours $*
```

This means that each occurrence is chained - so if it terminates abnormally the next instance won't be scheduled - but I don't think there's a more robust solution without adding a lot of code/complexity.

Comment: Or make it touch a file when it's done, and use Cron to examine the age of the file periodically. You'll need a second lock file to indicate that work is in progress, or have the running job touch the first file often while it runs.

Comment: So your saying rlib should either chain them, or add a lot of code/complexity, tripleee?

Comment: Thanks for answers. Is there some daemon that runs my job, detects when it's terminated, then waits 2 hours and runs the job again. Surely, I don't want to add complexity to the code, I want a ready solution.

Comment: Depends on how bad / likely it is that the job fails to restart. For a robust script, I totally second your recommendation of `at`; that's why this ended up as a comment here.

Comment: Short answer - no - but it does occur to me that you could implement the job as daemon instead of a scheduled single run then inject a sleep(7200) at the end of the control loop. Of course this pre-suposes you know how to implement a daemon.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the `at` solution proposed, so here another solution:

1. Use `cron` to launch your every two hours
2. Upon startup, your application(*) checks if there's a pidfile.

   2.1 if it is present, then there may be another instance running: read contents of the file (pid) and see if that pid is the pid of an existing process, a zombie process or something else. If it is the pid of a running, existing process, then exit. If it is the pid of a zombie process then the previous job ended unexpectedly and then you have to delete the pidfile and go to step 3. Otherwise.
3. After deleting pidfile, you create a new one and put your pid into it. Then proceed to do your job.

*: In order not to add complexity, this application i cited could also be a simple wrapper that spawns your code using `exec`.

This solution can also be scripted quite easily.

### Hope it helps,

SnoopyBBT

Comment: I don't want to add any code to existing code. I need an external utility.

Answer (score 0):

If it looks complicated, here is another, dirtier solution:

```
while true ; do
    ./your_application
    sleep 7200
done
```

### Hope this helps,

SnoopyBBT